# System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.VerifyNotCompleted error in Marketplace Error Report

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, backgroundworker, windows-phone-8

I have got `System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.VerifyNotCompleted` as an error in my `stacktrace` report from the marketplace for windows phone. I am using `background worker` to do work in the background thread. This error is occurring more in `windows phone 8` than in windows phone 7.

Please can anyone explain this error?

Comment: What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: unfortunately they dont print the full stack trace in the error reports and I am unable to reproduce the case.

Comment: http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/SourceViewer/browse.aspx?assembly=SSCLI&namespace=System.ComponentModel&type=AsyncOperation

from the code, i assume the when calling the *Post*, the PostOperationCompleted is already called.

Comment: I am not using it. How can it be called?

Comment: Milan, if you're looking at the dumps up in the xls in create.msdn.com, hit F2 on the 'stack trace' fieldin excel and it should expand.  Then past that full stack trace in.  For example one of mine (that I must clean up) went from one line fourteen lines of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that helped me in this case was preventing access to background worker by two threads at the same time. I would suggest others to do the same and prevent simultaneous access to the worker by to threads.

Answer (score 0):

I have never got such an error, but I just tried to find if I could help you in some way. This is what I found:

```
private void VerifyNotCompleted()
{
  if (!this.alreadyCompleted)
  {
    return;
  }
  throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("Async_OperationAlreadyCompleted"));
}
```

Just see if this helps out in any damn way. I am totally clueless about this exception, just tried sharing my search result. It might not be right too. Do let me know.